# To boot Ubuntu Linux from .img file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, img

I have installed Ubuntu Linux on an .img file which contains gpt partition table with just single partition.
I have not created boot partition but it just has root partition which is having ext4 filesystem.
I want to boot it in a physical machine not in virtual machine using that image.
Windows is already installed in my laptop.
The img file is located in sda5 by the name aa.img
Please explain how to do easily and mainly I am a new user to Linux
Thanking I advance

Comment: See this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/32506 . It answers your question.

Comment: Actually its not answering I only wrote answer to clarify my question. Hey wait I think you didn't understand what I said. I have installed Ubuntu on vhd in VirtualBox. Later I converted it to image file(I mean example.img) using poweriso software. Now I want to boot that img using my physical machine. And that img file contains gpt partition table and first partition is root partition thats all.